# Android: List of available trusted root certificates

Tags: android, ca

Is there a android developer page that lists all of the trusted root CAs?

I know I can just pull the file, and list them using keytool - looking for a published web page.

Comment: Have you managed to retrieve an "official" list?

Comment: There doesnt seem to be any official doc on this, but may be instead of pulling it out of the emulator, looking it through aosp might mean something - https://android.googlesource.com/platform/libcore/+/master/luni/src/main/files/cacerts/

Comment: // , @Varun your link 404s

Answer (score 12):

In Jelly bean you can find the trusted CA list by navigating to

Settings -> Security -> Trusted credentials.

Comment: In Oreo 8.1 it's bit more hidden:

Settings > System > Security & Location > Encryption & Credentials > Trusted Ceredentials

Answer (score 2):

I haven't found an official page. However, here is shown how to get the list of trustes certs from an android device: http://www.andreabaccega.com/blog/2010/09/23/android-root-certification-authorities-list/

There are also all certs published which were found on an that particular Android 2.2 Froyo.

Comment: // , This doesn't actually answer the question, but I guess Google just hasn't published a list of the Android pre-installed CAs.

Answer (score 1):

Coming too late to the party, but still... Although it is not an official document, you can find few lists of system trusted certificates taken from Android devices [here](http://kibitzer.funsite.cz/androidcertlist/index.php).